# Prove that double negation elimination is a derivated rule

Tags: logic, proof-explanation, propositional-calculus, natural-deduction

If $B=\{\wedge i, \wedge e_1, \wedge e_2, \vee i_1, \vee i_2, \vee e, \to i, \to e, \neg i, \neg e\}$, how can I prove that $\neg\neg e$ is a derivated rule from $B$ and proof-by-contradiction?

Comment: What is P, C?  What do you mean by adding a set B with P(set B)C?

Comment: It is Proof By Contradiction (or Reductio Ad Absurdum)

Comment: How exactly does your PBC rule look?

Comment: @HenningMakholm ¬φ ... ⊥ | φ

Comment: Does B include $\bot i$

Comment: If you have a $\bot$ symbol, then what do your $\neg$i and $\neg$e rules look like?

Comment: @amWhy, I never saw ⊥i, maybe you're talking about ¬e: φ ¬φ | ⊥

Comment: @HenningMakholm, ¬i: φ ... ⊥ | ¬φ

Comment: To get your contradiction, Premise $\lnot\lnot \phi$.    Assume $\lnot \phi$.  $(\lnot \phi \land \lnot \lnot \phi)$ ($\land i$). $\;\;\bot$. Therefore $\phi$.   We conclude $\lnot\lnot \phi\to \phi$.  And we can prove the other direction as well.

Answer (score 2):

Assume $\neg\neg\psi$. You want to prove $\psi$.

**Hint:** $\psi$ will be the conclusion of the proof-by-contradiction rule.

The rest of your proof *really* ought to write itself now.

Comment: The only way I was able to do it is using the Rule of Explosion, where I can conclude anything from a contradiction, but the Rule of Explosion is not inside B, so I can't really use it :/

Comment: @RafaelSantos: Your PBC rule becomes explosion if you just choose not to use the assumption for anything.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: I also need to derivate the Rule of Explosion, and then I can use it as some kind o lemma, but how can I derivate anything from a contradiction?

Comment: @RafaelSantos: if you have a proof of $\bot$ and want to conclude $\varphi$, then assume $\neg\varphi$, prove $\bot$, and conclude $\varphi$ by PBC (discharging the assumption of $\neg\varphi$ that you never used).

Comment: And if you want to conclude something from a contradiction, that's exactly what your $\neg$e rule does. (Unless you call the $\bot$ symbol "contradiction", in which case see my previous comment).

Comment: But to prove that, should I use ⊥ as a premise? Otherwise how could I assume ¬φ and find a contradiction with just that?

Comment: @RafaelSantos: If you're in a situation where you want to use the rule of explosion, you _already have a proof that concludes $\bot$_ (because that is what you need as a premise for explosion). Put that proof in between "assume $\neg\varphi$" and "therefore, by PBC, we conclude $\varphi$".

Comment: @RafaelSantos Explosion is the inference rule: $\dfrac{\Gamma\vdash\bot}{\Gamma\vdash\varphi}{\tiny\sf EFQ}$, that if a contradiction can be derived from the assumptions, we can infer that *anything* may be derived from them. The "Proof by Contradiction" rule should be $\dfrac{\Gamma,\neg\psi\vdash\bot}{\qquad\Gamma\vdash\psi}{\tiny\sf RAA}$, that if a contradiction can be derived from $\neg\psi$ and other assumptions, we can infer that $\psi$ may be derived from those other assumptions. Similar yet quite different. Don't use *Ex Falso Quodlibet*. This is a job for *Reductio Ad Absurdum!*

Comment: I give up! How do you prove double negation elimination using RAA without citing rules that themselves seem to depend on double negation elimination? If you don't want to give it away, please list the rules and axioms of natural deduction that are required.

Comment: ffs, @DanChristensen. If you follow the hint in this answer, you end up having assumed $\neg\neg\psi$ and $\neg\psi$ and needing to conclude $\bot$. All that remains is _literally one single application_ of the $\neg$e rule that the OP quoted. (The entire talk about explosion is a detour).

Comment: @HenningMakholm Then what do you mean by $\neg$e?

Comment: @DanChristensen: The OP quoted the $\neg$e rule he's using in a comment under the question: "¬e: φ ¬φ | ⊥"

Comment: @HenningMakholm I have no idea how to finish the proof, but here is my attempt:  1. $\neg\neg P$ (assume), 2. $\neg P$ (assume) 3. $\neg \neg P \land \neg P$ (obtain contradiction) 4. $\cdots$  n. $P$.

Comment: @DanChristensen: 3. $\bot$ (by $\neg$e, 2, 1).

Comment: @HenningMakholm Please complete the proof to obtain $P$.

Comment: @DanChristensen: That follows by RAA, 3, discharging 2.

Comment: @HenningMakholm But discharging 2 gives you $\neg\neg P$. It gets you nowhere.

Comment: @DanChristensen: I don't think you're using the RAA rule that the OP [said _he_ is using](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2797351/prove-that-double-negation-elimination-is-a-derivated-rule/2797412?noredirect=1#comment5767482_2797351) (assume $\neg\varphi$, derive $\bot$, conclude $\varphi$). You seem to be confusing it with the OP's $\neg$i [rule](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2797351/prove-that-double-negation-elimination-is-a-derivated-rule/2797412#comment5767506_2797351) (assume $\varphi$, derive $\bot$, conclude $\neg\varphi$).

Comment: @HenningMakholm Isn't that bit unusual? When I use RAA, I simply negate the assumption being discharged.

Comment: @DanChristensen: No, that is exactly what distinguishes ordinary negation introduction (which is intuitionistically valid) from the kind of indirect proof that is _not_ intuitionistically valid. Terminology conventions seem to be a bit unstable about which of these is called RAA, though.

Comment: @HenningMakholm +1 Thanks. That's very interesting. So, if you have RAA that eliminates $\neg$, you can derive the elimination of $\neg\neg$ rule. Is there any way to derive it using the other form of RAA?

Comment: @DanChristensen: Not with the other rules that have been mentioned here, because they are all intuitionistically valid, but double-negation elimination _isn't_. Other additional rules that would allow it are could be to declare $\neg\varphi\lor\varphi$ to be an axiom, or something like _Peirce's law_, e.g.: "Assume $\alpha\to\beta$, derive $\alpha$, discharge the assumption and conclude $\alpha$".